# Map multiple columns to the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm

Imagine a simple I-O-U app where there are a `User` model and a `Transaction` model.

The `User` table has the following columns:

- id
- name

The `Transaction` table has the following columns:

- lender_id (foreign key to `User.id`)
- borrower_id (foreign key to `User.id`)
- date

A user can only lend or borrow to another user that exists in the `User` table.

An example would be:

```
User:

 id | name
-------------
  1 | name A
  2 | name B
  3 | name C

Transaction:

 lender_id | borrower_id |  date
----------------------------------
     1     |     2       |  date1
     1     |     3       |  date2
     3     |     2       |  date3
```

How would I implement the associations in the model classes?

Comment: do you need [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) ?

Comment: What other attributes are you storing for the transactions and how do you plan to use them in your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On transaction:

```
belongs_to :lender, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :borrower, :class_name => "User"
```

On user:

```
has_many :loans, :class_name => "Transaction", :foreign_key => "lender_id"
has_many :debts, :class_name => "Transaction", :foreign_key => "borrower_id"
```

This gives you:

```
u = User.first
u.loans # [transaction, transaction, ...]
u.debts # [transaction, transaction, ...]
```

And

```
t = Transaction.first
t.lender # User
t.borrower # User
```

Hope this helps!